# twitter bootstrap dropdown menu javascript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I am having some trouble making the dropdown menus in twitter bootstrap work. Here is what I have for the navbar code.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <a class="brand">Title of website</a>
                        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                            <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Link 1<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 2</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Link 2<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 2</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have seen many different tutorials/examples on this, and I am not to sure what I am doing wrong, I have included jquery and the bootstrap-dropdown.js files at the end of the document.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {  
          $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();  
      });
</script>
```

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I don't find any error in your code, seems like you are

```
missing or not being loaded bootstrap-dropdown.js file

moreover please add bootstrap.js core file (as added in jsfiddle in below link)
```

check this jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/mastermindw/kbzxV/

Comment: hmm I have not seen the bootstrap.js core file, I cannot seem to find the download on the github

Comment: i meant this file
http://fiddle.jshell.net/js/lib/bootstrap-2.0.2.js but this was optional, you can find the bootstrap file structure here which does include bootstrap.js file http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/getting-started.html#download-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
//use bootstrap css
//latest jquery
//add bootstrap.js
//and paste your html
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="Styles/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style>
        .box
        {
            border: 1px solid red;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">
                <div class="navbar">
                    <div class="navbar-inner">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <a class="brand">Title of website</a>
                            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                            <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Link 1<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 2</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Link 2<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 2</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I attempted to use the supplied code and it has no effect. Could it possibly be the version of jquery? I have attempted to use both 1.x and 2.x. both minimized and non.

Comment: That was the problem indeed, I did not include bootstrap.js into the file. Thanks for the help

Comment: @d4rk0wl Please vote up my answer..so any body can find answer

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested the code and it should work. See this [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ijarud/1/edit) with your code

One minor update. The `.brand` element should be the child of navbar and not of `ul`, since that is invalid:

```
 <div class="navbar">
    <a class="brand">Title of website</a>
       <div class="navbar-inner">
           <ul class="nav">
               <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
```

You don't event have to call `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();` - as you can see the demo above

Comment: Thanks for the tip I corrected that issue. :) I think there might be a problem with my js calls

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to run.

Check out this example: http://jsfiddle.net/vZQ7S/

You could try to check the developer console for any error messages there.

Maybe you are not linking the javascript libraries to the correct file path?

Also try to run

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
```

in the developer console and watch for error messages.